# Плавный переход из display:none в display: block

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть у нас вот это

```css
#vhod {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 670px;
    top: -250px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

Это и есть форма входа, в этом диве она находится.

При помощи JS я вызываю эту форму, кликнув на кнопку, она появляется резко, а мне нужно плавно. В JQuery я не разбираюсь, готовым вариантом воспользоваться не могу.

Вот JS код, вызывающий `#vhod`

```js
function signClick () { 
    document.getElementById('sign').click(); 
 }

function doFunction() {
    document.getElementById("vhod").style.display = "block";
}
```

Comment: Проверяйте, есть элемент уже или нет.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```js
document.getElementById('sign').onclick = function() {
  $('#vhod').fadeIn();
}
```

```css
#vhod {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<button id="sign">Display</button>

<div id="vhod"></div>
```

Comment: окей, я сделал, но теперь #vhod появляется при открытии страницы, не подчиняется скрипту. Думаю, надо как-то организовать JQuery клик

Comment: поместите это в doFunction() вместо document.getElementById("vhod").style.display = "block";

Comment: Ничего не изменилось

Comment: скопируйте весь код

Comment: Самый первый код так же в doFunction()?

Comment: замените ваш код

Comment: Теперь fadeIn() заработал, но работает очень криво, за секунду он проявляется, растворяется и снова проявляется. Есть какие-то настройки или я что-то не так сделал?

Comment: скорее всего у вас что-то с кодом, вы удалили doFunction?

Comment: Да, удалил. Если вернуть его на место будет точно такой же результат

Comment: можно весь код?

Comment: В HTML файле в тэге <script> расположен код
 document.getElementById('sign').onclick = function() {
  $('#vhod').fadeIn();
}

Comment: Всё, разобрался. У меня стоял transition, не заметил его. Спасибо огромное за помощь.

Comment: Незачто, рад помочь

Comment: Ещё один вопрос появился) У меня так же есть затемнение (#shadow), обычный div с background-color:rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);, так вот при плавном появлении формы входа вместе с ним должно появляться это затемнение. Оно появляется, правда форма нет :с

Comment: В идеале должна появляться форма на затемненном фоне.

Comment: не совсем понимаю что нужно, почему на задать бокс шадоу?

Comment: Я уже всё решил, спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Для этого в jQuery есть методы `fadeIn()` и `fadeOut()`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  $("#show").click(function() {
    $("#block").fadeIn();
  });
  
  $("#hide").click(function() {
    $("#block").fadeOut();
  });
});
```

```css
#block {
  display: none;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #80ffff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="show">Show</button>
<div id="block">
  <button id="hide">Hide</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не ошибаюсь, то в свойстве transition нужно указывать, к какому свойству применять анимацию. Объявление этого свойства имеет вид:

> transition: property duration timing-function delay|initial|inherit;

В вашем случае

```
#vhod {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    left: 670px;
    top: -250px;
    transition: display 0.5s;
}
```